# Integrate Syncfusion with ASP.NET MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, charts, syncfusion, column-chart

I am using Syncfusion with ASP.NET MVC 4.0 with C#.

I have all the code ready but just need to implement in My code. I have create the demo code with MVC 5 and now I have to implement it in MVC 4 so what is the process and what are the necessary files I need to include by manually or by nuget?

I tried to implement but in CSHTML I don't know why EJ() is not able to use.

Any help will be appreciate..!!!

Answer (score 0):

To configure and install Syncfusion assemblies in your application using Nuget packages, refer to the below documentation link:
https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/installation-and-deployment#configuring-syncfusion-nuget-packages-in-visual-studio

To manually integrate into existing application, refer to the below documentation link:
https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/getting-started#for-existing-applications